# How to get the value inside a input name in html using php

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how to get the value of name in input tag using php?

```
<input type="text name="x" value="myFunction(this.name)">
```

it should return the value of the name tag x
im not sure about the syntax "this" if it will get the value of name tag which is x.

Comment: Use it in a form and submit it, lookup PHP's $_POST

Comment: Javascript isn't executed in the `value` attribute, it's just a literal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the value in PHP you have to make form, example

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="field">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then by post method of php you can get value . Example:

```
 <?php 
 echo $_POST['field'];
 ?>
```